# automate aws keys into credential file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am building a scrip to automatically take values from aws sts get-session-token and populate my ~/.aws/credentials file. I can independently run these tasks

1. aws sts get-session-token --serial-number <> -token-code <>
2. manually take the values from the output and run "aws configure set aws_access_key_id xxxxxx --profile abc " etc...

is there a way to get the output from step 1 as a variable and pass specific values to as inputs to step 2 ?

THanks

Comment: [Have you considered exporting them as environment variables instead?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Comment: There's already things that do this: take a look at aws-vault.
https://www.qualimente.com/2018/10/25/how-to-use-aws-vault-to-assume-a-role-in-an-aws-account/
https://www.qualimente.com/2018/10/25/how-to-use-aws-vault-to-assume-a-role-in-an-aws-account/

Comment: i have to use MFA token, so the values change every time